# ExtJS 6.0.0 executive-dashboard templates build error "@theme-background-image: Theme image not found"

Tags: css, image, extjs, build

I use *ExtJS 6.0.0* executive-dashboard templates to build app. But show some strange warns:

> [WRN] @theme-background-image: Theme image not found: images/dd/drop-yes.png
>   
> [WRN] @theme-background-image: Theme image not found: images/dd/drop-add.png
>   
> .
>   
> .
>   
> .
>   
> [WRN] @theme-background-image: Theme image not found: images/tab/tab-navigation-close.png

[image: Sencha app build cmd warn show]

How do I solve the problem?